# Why there is only one option in Closing > Off-topic > Migration?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I want to close [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/119493/14341) as belonging to another Stack Exchange site:

[image]

But when I click on it, there is only one option to choose:

[image]

Is this normal? There is no information stating that I can only VTC a question as belonging to Academia Meta specifically, according to the [Privileges](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page:

[image]

Comment: Totally normal. When I am not on my phone I will find the relevant question on the main meta. You can always flag it for 
mod attention and we can migrate it.